devextreme DataGrid filterRow for lookup column loads all data for big datasets
My database has a table with a large number of rows, and a pagination of 10 rows is displayed in the datagrid.
When you click show list in the lookup column (lookup has its own datasource in which there are only 5 values) in the filter row, the datagrid datasource starts loading absolutely ALL rows, with all expands, just to show a list of 5 elements.
I saw that dealextreme has its own header filter data source for header Filter, but there is no such thing for rowfilter.
How can I solve the problem so that rowfilter does not load all the data, but uses data from the lookup datasource as a list of possible values?

